SUM aggregates on multi level autoreference table in ABAP CDS
I have an auto-referenced table with "storage location".



Location
Higher Level Location




A



A1
A


AA1
A1


AAA1
AA1


AAAA1
AAA1


B




In another table, I have some stock in AAA1.
I have already a CDS view that sum my stock by location.



Location
Stock




A
0


A1
0


AA1
0


AAA1
25


AAAA1
0


B
0



Can I do a sum in one select for a common aggregation and see my stock for A / A1 / AA1 and AAA1 ?



Location
Aggr_Stock




A
25


A1
25


AA1
25


AAA1
25


AAAA1
0


B
0



or am I obliged to go with AMDP to distribute AAAA1 to AAA1,AA1,A1 and so on for each entry and then do a join between my stock CDS view and this view?
I know it could lead to an infinite loop if bad configured.
Thanks for any help,
Regards,
GRI.

Can't relate on name because real name will be E500, F45, J78 without any alphabetical rules

I have an auto-referenced table, In another table, I have already a CDS: give the code of all of those tables/views, and then we can suggest smth
